# How to make a Contact Form 7 responsive

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form

I need to make my Contact form 7 responsive. It is aligned right of an image but covers the image when screen size is reduced.

Image css

```
#ImageDiv{
margin-right: auto;
max-width:800px;
top: -30px;
position: relative;
left: -25px;
```

}

```
<div id="ImageDiv"><img alt="" src="https://image.png" height="auto" />
```

Contact Form 7

```
<div style="background-color:green;padding:5px 5px 5px 5px">
<div style="text-align: center;color:white;padding-bottom:5px">HEADER</div>

<div style="margin-bottom:5px"><div style="color:white; display:inline-block;padding-right:10px;width:30%">Name:</div>
<div style=" display:inline-block;width:65%">[text* your-name]</div></div>

<div style="margin-bottom:5px"><div style="color:white; display:inline-block;padding-right:10px;width:30%">Surname:</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;width:65%">[text* your-name]</div></div>

<div style="margin-bottom:5px"><div style="color:white; display:inline-block;padding-right:10px;width:30%">Email:</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;width:65%">[text* your-name]</div></div>

<div style="margin-bottom:5px;text-align:center">[submit "SUBMIT"]</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does Contact Form 7 styles everything inline? Because if so, you may have to override the inline styles with !important

Comment: Contact Form 7 is already responsive?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I fully understood your question but I've constructed a JSFiddle for what I think you're trying to acheive.

The browser output of the contact form 7 plugin allows you to use CSS roughly like:

```
#form-holder form input {
width:100%;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K5HKt/1/

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this too. 
Here is what worked for me:

In styles.css, find the "Fields" section (in my css it was section 4.2).

look for:

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="date"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"],
select[multiple],
textarea {
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
-moz-transition: 0.3s;
-o-transition: 0.3s;
-webkit-transition: 0.3s;
transition: 0.3s;
background: #f6f6f7;
border: 1px solid #eaeaeb;
color: #acaeaf;
line-height: normal;
padding: 0.6429em 0.7143em;
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Then I simply added:

```
width:85%;
```

So I now had:

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="date"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"],
select[multiple],
textarea {
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
-moz-transition: 0.3s;
-o-transition: 0.3s;
-webkit-transition: 0.3s;
transition: 0.3s;
background: #f6f6f7;
border: 1px solid #eaeaeb;
color: #acaeaf;
line-height: normal;
padding: 0.6429em 0.7143em;
-webkit-appearance: none;
width:85%;
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the [Smart Grid-layout design for cf7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) plugin which has a grid form editor as well as giving you many other features to make responsive and complex forms.